# ASP.net MVC validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following set for drop down in asp.net mvc

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DataId, ((IEnumerable<ProgrammeModel>)ViewBag.Data).Select(option => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name),
            Value = option.DataId.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (option.DataId== Model.DataId)
        }), "Choose...", new { Class = "input", id = "DataId" 

    })
```

And in model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="The Data field is required.")]
public int DataId { get; set; }
```

But when the validation happens on form submit I am getting the error message for this field as

**The Int32 field is required.**

where I was expecting the result as

**The Data field is required**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, It seems that in the controller you have ViewBag.DataId and it is causing confusion to the validation.
Please try removing it and let me know if it is ok now.

Thanks,
Dimitar

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DataId,
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.Data as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
                      "DataId", "Name"), "Choose")
```